# JAXB-RI Marshalling generic list gives incorrect output

Tags: java, xml, generics, jaxb, marshalling

We have a complicated structure of classes that we are trying to marshal to an xml file using JAXB-RI. The marshalling seems to work correctly with Spring's jaxb2Marshaller but not with the jaxb-ri, which is what we are trying to use. (We're using Java 6 and jaxb-2.1.13)

This is an example of the output we currently see after marshalling with JAXB-RI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <specificCompanyList>
       <org>com.ourcompany.etc.etc.TypeOfCompany@56cb0eed</org>
       <org>com.ourcompany.etc.etc.TypeOfCompany@3125a57</org>
       ....
     </specificCompanyList>
```

This is what we want to see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<specificCompanyList>
  <org id="123456" name=" COMPANY NAME 1"/>
  <org id="098765" name=" COMPANY NAME 2"/>
  ....
</specificCompanyList>
```

Here is some info about our class structure. Apologies if it's confusing -- I want to lay everything out on the table. Class names and paths have been changed and shortened as well.

Class that becomes the root element:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="specificCompanyList")
public class SpecificCompanyLookup extends BaseCompanyLookup<TypeOfCompany> {
    public SpecificCompanyLookup() {}
    ....
}
```

BaseCompanyLookup:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
abstract class BaseCompanyLookup<T extends OrgNode> implements Lookup {
    @XmlElement(name="org")
    final Set<T> companyList = new TreeSet<T>(.....);
}
```

OrgNode:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
classOrgNode extends BaseLookupItem {
}
```

BaseLookupItem:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BaseLookupItem {

    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String id;

    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String name;

    ....
}
```

A class that extends OrgNode:

```
class TypeOfCompany extends OrgNode {
    ....
}
```

So:
BaseLookupItem -> OrgNode -> TypeOfCompany

Does anyone know what is causing this bad output? How do we make the JAXB-RI marshaller generate the output that we need?

**EDIT:** We found the solution. This happened when we moved to WebLogic 12c, which has switched its JAXB default to the EclipseLink MOXy implementation. That implementation appears to have a bug for the case I described here. Following the instructions to switch to the Glassfish JAXB RI fixed this issue for us. Here are those instructions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24964/data_types.htm#CIHBHDGI

Comment: It sounds like you maybe have in fact hit a bug in MOXy.  I will investigate and post back with what I find.  In the meantime to avoid having to switch implementations try adding an @XmlSeeAlso(TypeOfCompany.class) annotation to the SpecificCompanyLookup class as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed this is in fact a bug in MOXy and have opened the following bug to track the issue https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=410001

I also confirmed that adding the @XmlSeeAlso annotation like this would be a workaround for this case.

```
@XmlSeeAlso(TypeOfCompany.class)
public class SpecificCompanyLookup extends BaseCompanyLookup<TypeOfCompany> {
    public SpecificCompanyLookup() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for creating the bug. We did switch to Glassfish by the time I wrote my "EDIT"; however, a different place in our code was exhibiting the same behavior in all cases, and the @XmlSeeAlso was the correct solution for that.